# Powershell create top navigation bar with second level items

Tags: 2013, powershell, navigation, branding

I am creating a top nav hierarchy using Powershell.  I can create the first level nodes easily enough, but second level nodes nevver get created and I get no errors from the script.  Here is an example:

```
$web = get-spweb https://www.nga.dev
$node1 = New-Object         Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Products", "/Info/Pages/Content/ContentCatalog.aspx")
$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.AddAsFirst($node1)

$node2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Services", "/Info/Pages/Content/ServiceCatalog.aspx")
$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.Add($node2,$node1)

$node3 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Missions", "/")
$web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar.Add($node3,$node2)

$subNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("IA Missions","/")
$node3.Children.AddAsLast($subNode)
$node3.Update()
$subNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode("Other Missions","/")
$node3.Children.AddAsLast($subNode)
$node3.Update()
$web.Update()
```

I also notice that I need a valid URL in order for the node to show inthe top nav bar.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [CreateSPNavigationNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.spnavigationsitemapnode.createspnavigationnode.aspx) method and you can pass in the collection directly:

```
$subNode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.SPNavigationSiteMapNode]::CreateSPNavigationNode("IA Missions","/",[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.NodeTypes.AuthoredLinkPlain], $node3.Children)
```